# Disable file sharing on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, security, file-sharing

I want to disable file sharing (SMB) on Windows XP and I turned it off in the network properties dialog box, but the system is still listening on port 445. Is there a way to make it stop listening on 445 entirely? Is it still on in stealth mode?

[image]

Comment: Just install the patch for Windows XP that fixes the SMB exploit

Comment: @Ramhound Even with a fix for the current vulnerability, SMB is still a pretty large attack surface.

Comment: You can always use the built-in firewall, block everything except what you need to listen.

Comment: @Sam Good idea, block buggy software I don't use with... more buggy software I don't use. I have a better idea: turn the buggy software off.

Comment: The current answers don't actually disable SMBv1, this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-enable-and-disable-smbv1,-smbv2,-and-smbv3-in-windows-vista,-windows-server-2008,-windows-7,-windows-server-2008-r2,-windows-8,-and-windows-server-2012) explains how to do that

Comment: @Ramhound Don't follow your point about SMBv1. The current answers disable all versions of SMB, as per the question. Your linked article disables specific SMB versions for Vista+, not XP.

Comment: @Jimadine - The answers have been updated since I made that comment.....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured out how to do this from another post.

Add the following registry key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters`

`Name: SMBDeviceEnabled Type: DWORD (REG_DWORD) Data: 0`

This will completely disable SMB services and shutdown the server that listens on 445. Restart computer to take effect. You can verify that it is off by using netstat -an

Comment: Did you try disabling the Server service?

Comment: The correct action is to flag your question as a duplicate, not answer it without even attributing to the source Q&A.

Comment: This doesn't disable SMBv1 though

Comment: @Ramhound It shuts down port 445. What port is "SMBv1" using?

Comment: After adding the key, the command: 
     netstat -na | find "LISTENING" | find ":445", 

     returns empty - so nobody listening on 445

Comment: Seems like [this 2013 answer](https://superuser.com/a/630592) is a likely source for this post, which in turn relies on this [forum post from 2010](http://ssj100.fullsubject.com/t181-how-to-disable-ports-135-137-139-445-windows-xp#1210).

Answer (score 7):

#### Command line method

Assuming the current user is a member of the `Administrators` group, open a command prompt and enter:

```
reg add HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters /V SmbDeviceEnabled /T REG_DWORD /F /D 0
```

(this adds the required registry setting to disable SMB, and is the CLI equivalent of the OP's answer)

Then enter:

```
sc stop lanmanserver
sc config lanmanserver start= disabled
```

(this stops and disables the `server` service, a.k.a `lanmanserver`)

Restart your computer:

```
shutdown -r -t 01
```

After the restart, open a command prompt and enter the following command to verify that SMB is no longer listening on port 445:

```
netstat -na | find "LISTENING" | find ":445 "
```

If no output is returned by this command, you're all good!

#### Another possible method involving the GUI

...is to uninstall `File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks` completely:

1. Go to `Start` | `Control Panel`, and double-click the `Network
   Connections` applet.
2. Right-click `Local Area Connection` (i.e., the
   Internet-facing connection), and select `Properties`.
3. Select `File And Printer Sharing For Microsoft Networks`, and click the `Uninstall` button.
4. Choose `Yes` when prompted to uninstall the component. Close all dialog boxes and applets.

For those that might benefit from a guide with screenshots, see:
http://ca.huji.ac.il/services/security/sharingXP-uninstall.shtml

Comment: I already had Server turned off. It was still listening on 445. The port is owned by PID 4, which is basically the kernel, it is not a service. The service portion is, I think, just some kind of front end. The actual server itself is not actually in the "Server" service, so turning off Server, does not turn off the 445 listener.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your experience - belt n braces probably best! I'm seeing mixed results with regard whether you need to modify both registry setting & service state. On an XP box I tested, modifying the reg was enough, and on my own 7 box, stopping the service was enough. Possibly the order of modifications makes  a difference.

Answer (score 1):

As this vulnerability targets SMB and NetBT, it can be removed with cmd (if these services are not required)::

```
::Disable netbt service
net stop netbt & sc delete netbt
net stop netbios & sc delete netbios

::Disable Workstation Service
sc stop "LanmanWorkstation"
sc config "LanmanWorkstation" start= disabled
sc delete "LanmanWorkstation"

::Disable SMB feature (windows 7 or higher)
DISM /Online /Disable-Feature /FeatureName:SMB1Protocol /Remove /NoRestart
DISM /Online /Disable-Feature /FeatureName:SmbDirect /Remove /NoRestart

::File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks       
netcfg /u ms_server
```

Run this as administrator and restart PC. These commands will remove the services permanently. You may close the ports in firewall.

Comment: As this question is tagged windows-XP, are you sure DISM comes with XP?

Comment: It does not....

Comment: Hence I edit the post. See more about [Serverfault:: Optional feature on Windows XP](https://serverfault.com/questions/765920/get-a-list-of-installed-optional-features-on-windows-xp)

Comment: @Biswa Only the netcfg line in your commands is relevant to the parameters of OP's question i.e. disable SMB 445 in Win XP. But even netcfg is doubtful given it isn't a standard XP console util (https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=627079).